# How to convert this ASM diagram to register transfer level?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-level, register, algorithm

So we have this ASM diagram, which I have to convert into register transfer level. 
[image]

I have already done some similar examples and I will usually start with defining next-state logic, than output logic and register data path.

With this example I have trouble with defining next-state logic. If I make table of state transitions, I need to take also start, a and b in consideration. Since we have 4 states we need 4 bits for that + one bit for start, one for b!=0 and one for a > b. That is simply too much combinations to write on paper. I suppose that maybe there is simpler solution for this.

What does the ready A state do? I'm confused from the diagram.

Comment: This is not a state chart, so a notion of "next state" is meaningless here.

Comment: I am sure next state can be derived from this diagram, besides that is the question how to do so.